# Is there any well-established work that allows robots to communicate their decision-making using natural language?

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language-processing, reference-request, human-robot-interaction

I am searching for a well-established work that allows robots to communicate their decision-making using natural language.

For example, a robot's explanation could be "I did [task1] because [reason1] and [reason2]."

I know there is parallel research across different fields but I was wondering if anyone knows a good work with reusable code.

Thanks!

Comment: they did something like this in this big project https://ai.meta.com/research/cicero/diplomacy/